# JSON Newbie - permanently saving values to JSON between browser reloads

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I have an AJAX poll based on this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp

However, instead of writing the poll entries from the HTML radio button to an array in a text file (as outlined in the tutorial). I would like to write to a JSON file. At the moment the values from the radio button entry are sent to the JSON, but the file does not retain the value between browser refreshes. I think that this is probably an issue with my syntax or encoding - the server should have the correct permissions to write to the file. Any tips are greatly appreciated.

```
<?php $vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];
//get content of json
$filename = "poll.json";
$poll = file_get_contents($filename);
$json = json_decode($poll);
//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];
if ($vote == 0) {
$yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
$no = $no + 1;
}
//insert votes to json file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
$poll = json_encode($json);
fclose($fp);?>
```

At the moment the result is either:
{1||}
or
{||1} in the JSON file, I can't figure out how to save the values the way that they were saved to the .txt file version (as outlined here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_poll.asp)

---

**Update**

So based on the excellent advice I received I am much closer. I found that "w" was the correct option for the php as "a+" appended data in the JSON rather than updating the existing values.

I now have a JSON file which is updating the values that are added through the html radio buttons.

So the result looks like: [3,4]
AKA 3 votes from option 1 and 4 votes for option 2

Comment: Just create a valid json format you want to use and write that to the file. Then rewrite the way you generate that json string. From my limited udnerstanding, I see that you want to write the values of `#yes + || + $no`, which isn't valid json. Try using something like `{"pollname":"mypollname","value":"` + $vote + `"}`. And then change $array so that it uses the 0 or 1 from the "value" key in the json file.

Comment: What is `$content`? You call your file JSON, but write values to it like `1||0` that is absolutely not JSON, and so `json_decode` on it will certainly fail. Why do you store something in `$poll` near the end, if you don't use it?

Comment: Thanks both, thank you for flagging the issues with the syntax here. I now understand that there are fundamental issues with how I have written the values - I will learn more about the syntax and give it another go. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- You JSON format is not JSON. Values like `0||1` are not JSON, and so `json_encode` on it will fail. One of the benefits of true JSON is that you don't have to juggle with delimiters like `||`.
- The `$content` variable is nowhere initialised.
- You encode something as JSON near the end, but don't do anything with it.
- You call a variable `$json` when you intend to store *decoded* JSON in it. That is really confusing. Don't call such a variable `$json`.

Here is some alternative code:

```
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];
//get content of json
$filename = "poll.json";
if (!file_exists($filename)) { // First time ever
    $poll = [0, 0];
} else {
    $poll = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
    if (!$poll) $poll = [0, 0];
}
// increment counter for vote
$poll[$vote] += 1;
//insert votes to json file
file_put_contents($filename, json_encode($poll));
```

Comment: Thank you so much all, @trincot you have gotten me much closer and I am very thankful for that. The only issue that persists is how to pull the data from the array so that it is displayed in the HTML.

Comment: You're welcome. However, this really is a follow-up question. I think the original question (*"permanently saving values to JSON between browser reloads"*) has been resolved. If you have a further question, you really should post that as a new question. I hope you understand.

Comment: I have marked your reply as the answer as it got me a LOT closer. The second part of the question, which I have now removed comes down to working with the values in the poll array I'll look for some other posts related to that - many thanks

Comment: Thanks, and don't hesitate to ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at this line:

```
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
```

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fopen.php), mode "w":

> places the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length

In other words: Each request overrides the whole file with it's contents.

To fix this, use mode "a+".

```
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you change code and this is undefined:

```
$content[0]
```

In

```
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
```

Source Is:

```
<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>
```